# Cannot set parameter through SetParameters

Tags: ros2, parameter-server

I have a node that is launched with some parameters which are considered global, hence, every node can access it through a service call with the default services `get_parameters` and  `set_parameters`. While I can successfully read the parameters, I'm not able to SET them, i.e. to change their values.

Here the code for the node which is in charge of setting the parameter.

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.srv import GetParameters, SetParameters
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterDescriptor
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.msg import Parameter
from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_subscriber',
                         allow_undeclared_parameters=False, 
                         automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides=False,
                         )
        # self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 1  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.on_timer)
        self.i = 0

      
        self.set_param_client = self.create_client(SetParameters,
                                         '/global_parameter_server/set_parameters')
        self.set_param_service_ready = False        
        self.param_received = False

    def on_timer(self):
        if self.set_param_service_ready:
            if self.param_received:
                # self.get_logger().info('Param received')
                pass
            else:
                if self.result.done():
                    self.get_logger().info(
                        f'{self.result.result()}')
                    self.param_received = True
                else:
                    self.get_logger().info('Request non finished')
        else:
            if self.set_param_client.service_is_ready():

                request = SetParameters.Request()
                param = Parameter()
                param.name = 'zr30_yolo_detection_flag'

                request.parameters = [param]
                # Call request
                self.result = self.set_param_client.call_async(request)
                self.set_param_service_ready = True
            else:
                # Check if the service is ready
                self.get_logger().info('Service is not ready')


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalSubscriber()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The service call is completed, however, it is never successfull since it always gives this reason `'Static parameter cannot be undeclared`

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/aut/.ros/log/2023-09-22-12-47-20-725281-aut-7996
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [global_parameter_server-1]: process started with pid [7997]
[INFO] [minimal_subscriber-2]: process started with pid [7999]
[global_parameter_server-1] [INFO] [1695379641.193061411] [global_parameter_server]: GlobalParameterServer started
[global_parameter_server-1] [INFO] [1695379641.194204782] [global_parameter_server]: False
[minimal_subscriber-2] [INFO] [1695379643.236667722] [minimal_subscriber]: rcl_interfaces.srv.SetParameters_Response(results=[rcl_interfaces.msg.SetParametersResult(successful=False, reason='Static parameter cannot be undeclared')])
```

Comment: The error is coming from the global_parameter_server rejecting your requested changes. Please edit your question to explain what is that running and how are you invoking it and setting it up?